# Is model.save_weights necessary?

Tags: keras

I wonder if `model.save_weights()` is necessary at the end of training. Suppose I already have a checkpoint as blow:

```py
checkpoint = ModelCheckpoint(                                         
                'weights.{epoch:02d}-{val_loss:.2f}.h5',
                monitor='val_loss',                               
                verbose=0,
                save_best_only=True,
                save_weights_only=True,
                mode='min',                           
                period=1)
```

which should already save the weights in a separate `h5` file. Is `model.save_weights()` still needed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a checkpoint to save the model weights after each training epoch, which would make an extra call to `model.save_weights()` obsolete. For this you need to set:

1. `save_weights_only=True`, as you only want to save the weights
2. `period=1`, to save the weights after **each** epoch
3. `save_best_only=False`, because otherwise you do not save models where the metric given as `monitor` argument does not improve.

**In the case of** `save_best_only=True` **you might miss to save the final weights**, so if you are interested in them, you need to call `model.save_weights()` explicitly after training.

---

Note that what will actually be saved depends also on your input for the first argument, the `filepath`:

- A **fix** filepath, e.g. `'weights.h5'`, leads to a **single** saved weight file.

  - If `save_best_only=False` it is overwritten with the current weights after each epoch.
  - If `save_best_only=True` and the value of the monitored metric got better, the weight file will be overwritten, otherwise nothing happens.
- A **formatted** filepath as in your example `'weights.{epoch:02d}-{val_loss:.2f}.h5'`, can lead to multiple saved weight files.

  - If `save_best_only=False` you get a file for each epoch.
  - If `save_best_only=True` you get a file for each epoch where the monitored metric improved over the best value monitored over all previous epochs. The previously saved files, however, are **not overwritten**, because their filenames differ from the current one.